# Can we define resource for xamarin forms control template elsewhere other than app.xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build pages with a base template. I've used control template in app.xaml and it works great.

Here is what I have done

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App3.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="baseTemplate">
```

But can I define this control template resource anywhere other than app.xaml because the app.xaml is getting cramped. Can I have separate folder for templating. How can I achieve this?
Any guide or tutorial will also help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a ResourceDictionary in any XAML file. See the Xamarin documentation here:

There's also a good Xamarin University class on this:

https://university.xamarin.com/classes/track/xamarin-forms#xam140-resources-and-styles

If you're new to Xamarin, I suggest you hit Xamarin University. The self-guided courses are free.